# What is GVW file format?

Tags: gps, convert, file-formats, garmin

I am wondering what is the format of theses files: gvw

http://tracking2016.vendeeglobe.org/gv5ip0/resources/weather/20161110-030000.gvw

It is meant to store somehow the weather data but I can't figure out what is the format of this file and how to read it.

It seems related to Garmin but I can't find any specs about that.

Is there anything to convert it to a more comon file format ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [DataTypes.net](https://datatypes.net/open-gvw-files#ext0):

> GVW file is a GeoVisu Waypoint Data. GeoVisu is a program that
>   displays georeferenced data (images, graphics) and downloads data
>   recorded by some GPS devices. GeoVisu has a Moving map navigation
>   function, which can be used with any NMEA 0183 compatible or Garmin
>   USB GPS device.

The [GeoVisu page](http://geovisu.free.fr/geovisu/english/geovdoca.htm) has this to say:

> GeoVisu uses its own data format to store data downloaded from Garmin
>   et Navilink GPS receivers. These are ASCII files. They can be easily
>   altered. See [format](http://geovisu.free.fr/geovisu/english/geovdoca.htm#gvwt) in [Appendix C](http://geovisu.free.fr/geovisu/english/geovdoca.htm#gvwt). Coordinate system is WGS84.